# Searching by Clicking a Cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

is there a function or some way to have excel return a result by clicking on a cell?

for example, if I have a list of groceries going down column B2:B10 and the isle they are located in going down C2:C10, I can use vlookup to find the isle I can find that certain item right? well I was wondering, using the same example as above, where I can enter grocery items in column B2:B10 and have a cell that returns the isle number each time I click the cell? so if I click cell B3 and B3 contains carrots, a cell (lets call it D2) D2 will return a number and that number is the isle number where the carrots can be located in. Does this make much sense? is It possible? thanks everyone *luv y'all*

Comment: I don't understand the benefit at all of deferring calculation.  If you have a data table somewhere that maps carrots to aisle 7, and bread to aisle 10, then once you type "Carrots" in B2 and press enter, then cell C2 will *immediately* contain "Aisle 7."  What you are proposing is a formula or script that will artificially prevent the display of "Aisle 7" in cell B2 until later, once the cell is clicked on.  I am not sure what the use case for this is, but I think your interests will be much better served using a different paradigm than Excel.

Comment: Could you provide a sample file?

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you describe can be achived with VBA programming in Excel for desktop (Windows or Mac).  You will need to work with the Worksheet Events, which can trigger code when, for example, the cell selection changes, or when a cell is double clicked.
The code can then perform a lookup and serve the result, either into a worksheet cell or as a dialog.

This kind of thing does not work in mobile Excel, so, you wouldn't be able to use it while walking your supermarket aisles.

Answer (score 0):

The example given actually would have no point as the result asked for would be right there next to your chosen cell.

But... one supposes you are just changing the circumstances for simplicity or to protect a private/business usage. Or perhaps want a way to pass that value on to something else (that falls into the "simplicity" category I guess).

What you ask for, exactly ask for, is, as `teylyn` says, not possible with Excel and its formulas or features. It is possible with VBA applied to Excel, or the couple other programming languages you can write macros with in Excel.

But... you can get ALMOST what you ask for, if you can settle for that.

The `CELL` function takes two parameters, but only the first is required. The first is a text label, in quotes, that tells it just what information you are seeking. The second is the cell you'd like the information for. (You can give it a range, but it only gives a result for the "first" cell in the range.)

If you use the function but do not specify the cell, Excel uses the currently selected cell. So clicking cell B6 would see it return information for cell B6. The problem is that it will NOT automatically update. So you see a value in the cell D2, perhaps 4, and click a different food item, expecting to see it change. No change.

Pressing `F9` to recalc the spreadsheet will force the change though. You can use a formula based upon this. The idea would be that you must click a food item, then press `F9`... not exactly what is asked for, but perhaps it would be close enough.

I tried the usual wheezes to force it to change automatically:  enabling "iterative calculation" (allowing circular referencing) and adding a simple function based math operation to it (as in `0*NOW()`). Neither helps. So general recalc (press `F9`) or edit the cell and press Enter (as in press `F2`, then `Enter`... not making any real edit) forcing Excel to recalc anything involving the cell. With modern Excel's recalc methodology, they do the same thing, so the first, a single keypress is better.

A formula that does the trick is the following. You might make one up in probably three dozen ways though, depending upon the version/product you have to use, and the functions you like, not to mention your exact setup and intended use.

```
=INDEX(B2:C7,  TEXTAFTER(CELL("address"),"$",2),  2)
```

The nice, new `TEXTAFTER` makes it easy to strip off the row portion of the cell address. Not all that long ago, a few years now, you'd've needed to wrap its Text result in `VALUE` or do some other coercive technique to change it to a number. But Excel has gotten very good with that. When a result is clearly meant to be numerical, it will look past the idea that Text was returned. So no need for `VALUE` but earlier versions might need it. After that it's a bog-standard `INDEX/MATCH`.